# I get the error: "invalid types 'long int[int] for array subscript"

Tags: c, int

in computer science we were given a few exercises to learn c coding.
One of those exercises was to create a function copyField which is given 3 arguments: targetField sourceField and the Length of the field.

We should create a function that takes the sourceField (has to have long-values)
and copies it into targetField.

My code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

//declaration of the function
long copyField(long targetField, long sourceField, int length);

int main(void){

  //sField will be variable afterwards
  /*sField equals sourceField; tField equals targetField; 
  len equals Length of sField 
  */

  long sField[]={12341234,2343233,3432424,4235252354,53254234};
  long tField[sizeof(tField)/sizeof(int)];
  int len=sizeof(sField)/sizeof(int);

 /*commented because I have to fix the error first
  copyField(tField,sField,len);
 */

 //print out the targetField

  for(int i=0;i<=sizeof(tField)/sizeof(int);i++){
    printf("%d",sField[i]);
  }

  return(0);

}

//function
long copyField(long a,long  b,int c){

  //for i < length of sField 

  for(int i=0;i<c;i++){
    /*targetField should be filled with the content
    of sourceField
    */
    a[i]=b[i];
  }

}
```

Can you help me fix this problem? I'm kinda new to c it's been just a couple of weeks now so I hope you can help me...

Comment: `long tField[sizeof(tField)/sizeof(int)];`. That makes no sense, how can the compiler know `sizeof(tField)` when it hasn't been completely declared yet? And `sizeof(int)` is also wrong, it should be `sizeof(long)`.

Comment: `long a` and `long b` are merely longs, but you are trying to access them as if they were arrays

Comment: @Pablo 1. yeah that was a typo.. 2.but sizeof int works and gives the correct value.

Comment: @ChristianGibbons ok i changed them to this: `long *a` and `long *b`

Comment: I don't know your compiler does not give you an error for this. My gcc (6.4.0) gives me an error for `int x[sizeof x / sizeof(int)];`: *error: `x` undeclared (first use in this function)*

Comment: And `int len=sizeof(sField)/sizeof(int);` is also wrong, you're constantly passing the incorrect types. Correct version is: `size_t len = sizeof(sField)/sizeof(long);` and even better `size_t len = sizeof sField / sizeof *sField;`

Comment: @Pablo it does give me an error, like i said it was a typo it should be `long tField[sizeof(>s<Field)/sizeof(int)]`

Comment: Ok, typo about `sField`, the type you are using is still wrong, you should use `/sizeof(long)`. It recommend using `long tField[sizeof sField / sizeof *sField];` **THAT** gives you the correct amount of elements. I recommend to avoid `sizeof(<type>)` whenever you can do `sizeof variable`. The former is easier to get wrong, the latter is more robust and will yield correct results every time.

Comment: `/sizeof(int)` would give you the correct amount only when `long` and `int` have the same size. On my system `long` is 8 bytes long, `int` is 4. The way you did it, I would end up with an array twice as long as needed and the `for`-loop would overflow the buffer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `targetField` and `sourceField` arguments of the function are not arrays and you are accessing them as arrays.
Also `long` is not unsigned, you may be assigning too large value to it.

Try this

```
long copyField(long targetField[], long sourceField[], int length);
```